# Assertions alternative for production code

Tags: java, production, assertion

first: I love Assertions! Especially the "org.assertj" framework. I think its a very helpful tool to validate parameters at runtime. Now I'm looking for alternatives cos of the following reasons:

- AssertJ creates for shaded maven compilation an jar oversize (> 4.5 Mb)
- Everyone says 'Dont use assertions at runtime'

Is there a more lightweight solution available to validate method or class parameter without getting lost in many IF statements?